# HTML id's to one single php variable?

Tags: php, variables, webforms

Please help...

I would like to know how you display multiple html id's (e.g. firstname & surname) in one .php variable (e.g $firstname )...

Here's my code:

```
$customerFirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$customerSurname = $_POST['surname'];

$customerFullname = ''; // first & surname id's of customer retrieved from enquiryForm
```

Thanks in advance...

Thanks All for your comment... really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **concatination** of two strings like

```
$customerFirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$customerSurname = $_POST['surname'];

$customerFullname = $customerFirstname .' '. $customerSurname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you mean an array or a string, so I'll provide an example of both.

Array:

```
$customerFullName = array($customerFirstName, $customerLastName);
```

Concatenation:

```
$customerFullName = $customerFirstName . ' ' . $customerLastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the variables in other. Like it:

```
$customerFirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$customerSurname = $_POST['surname'];

$customerFullname = $customerFirstname.' '.$customerSurname;
```

Answer (score -1):

The quick and easy solution , Use an array . A better approach , use an object . In the second case you can group all user related functions , properties together , so my vote goes for objects .

Comment: Whats the difference between an array and an object? I have one instance where I have to produce the fullname of the customer using $customerFirstname and $customerSurname to create $customerFullname. But I have another where I'd like to use  $functionDay, $functionMonth & $functionYear to create $functionDate

Comment: An array is just a data-structure that enables you to store more than one values , while with objects you can have logic that is you can implement functions that are specific to the context of that object . For eg . Suppose you need to store user info in a database then the user class can consist of the functions addUser(),delUser(). And in this case you can have a returnFullName() , which concatenates both the first and last name and returns it . Similarly you can have a function to concatenate the dates in a date class or in the user class itself .

Comment: With me being new to .php I just wish to concatenate the values into a string for emailing the collated enquiryForm information. But as I progress I will look at storing the captured information in a DB so I will most likely use an object. Thanks for that....